# I am having an issue while calling json multiple time using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, for-loop

```
for(var j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j ++){
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/predict', tempArray[j])
    .fail(function(data,textStatus, error) {
      Probability = data.responseText;
      console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error);
    })

    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      Probability = data.classProbabilities[0];
      Array.prototype.push.call(resultPercentage, Probability);
    });
}
console.log(resultPercentage);
```

`tempArray` is an array of 10 objects. I am passing that array to json using for loop.
`resultPercentage` is printing 10 different results in one array.
It's keep changing sequence of the result in that array whenever I call that Json using for loop.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the problem... Since you have the 10 expected results. You know `.get()` is asynchrounous, right?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: Yes, So how can I get result synchronous ? Every time "resultPercentage" giving me results with an array of random sequence.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to "order" multiple ajax request sent to a server at almost the same time. The treatment order depends on the server. What you should do ti send an "identifier" along with the data, and manage to get this identifier back with the response. Then use it to "reorder" them. -- Like... Send an object instead : `{data:tempArray[j],id:j}`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: Okay, let me try

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: How can I pass that object in my program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and i did something like this:

```
    $.each( array, function( key, value ) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/example",
        data: JSON.stringify(value),
        async:false,
        success:something,
       fail:something
      });
   });
```

You can try this using for loop also. The async:false will stop it from running asynchronously.

Comment: This looks promising. Let me try !

Comment: Worked ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this. Note: You can't run a function inside the loop. Try it, if it works, let us know. If not, please provide your intention what actually you are wanting to do.

```
var tempArray = [];

for(var j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++){  
                   $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/predict', tempArray[j])
                    .fail(first)
                    .done(second);
    }
     console.log(resultPercentage);

function first(data, textStatus, error) {
                        Probability = data.responseText;
                        console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error);
                    }

function second(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    Probability = data.classProbabilities[0];
                    Array.prototype.push.call(resultPercentage, Probability);
                }
```

Comment: Suppose, In my program resultPercentage output is array of {15,88,30,55,7}. If I run my program again I am getting {30,55,7,15,88}. So sequence is keep changing. 

I want tempArray[0] answer at first position, tempArray[1] answer at second position in output array and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in comments, the treatment order of multiple ajax resquest sent *almost (we're talking microseconds)* at the same time depends on the server.

I don't know how a server manages that.
But **for sure**, it is not guaranteed they will be processed in order.

I only can answer with **theorical** suggestions...
Since I don't know what `http://localhost:8080/predict` does.
I don't even know if this is PHP.

---

So this only is the *principle* I would try to apply...
     I never tried... By the way. ;)

---

First thing I would do, is to pass the `j` loop counter as a request `id`.
Then, I would use [Ajax Global Events](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) to handle the responses, instead of `.fail()` and `.done()` within the loop.
This would shorten the `for` loop to this:

```
for(var j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j ++){
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/predict', '{data:tempArray[j],id:j}');   // Pass the array AND an id
}
```

Now, in `http://localhost:8080/predict`, get the data and do your stuff.
Keep the `id` to re-inject it in the json response.

```
<?php
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

// Do your stuff with $data...
// ...

// Add the passed id to the json actually produced:
echo '{id:' . $id . ', classProbabilities:[0.90], color:"blue", somethingElse:"Other data"}';

?>
```

Using the Ajax Global Events enables the use of some counters.
It is usefull to make sure all requests are complete before attempting to display results.
And even if some requests failed, you can display the results for the successful ones.

```
// Counters.
var completed_Ajax = 0;
var error_Ajax = 0;
var success_Ajax = 0;

// An array to get the resquest response order
var responseOrder = [];

// An array to have the resquest responses reordered (final result)
var resultPercentageOrdered = [];


// Error handler
$.ajaxError(function(request, status, error){
  error_Ajax++;
  console.log("Error #"+error_Ajax+":\n"+error);
});

// Sucess handler
$.ajaxSuccess(function(data){
  success_Ajax++;

  // Handle the data (your code untouched)
  console.log(data);
  Probability = data.classProbabilities[0];
  Array.prototype.push.call(resultPercentage, Probability);

  // Push the received id in array.
  responseOrder.push(data.id);

  if( success_Ajax == tempArray.length ){
    console.log("All resquests succeded.");
  }
});

// Completed request handler
$.ajaxComplete(function(){
  completed_Ajax++;

  if( completed_Ajax == tempArray.length ){
    console.log("All resquests done.");
  }

  if( (error_Ajax + success_Ajax) == tempArray.length ){  // Even if there are errors... Show results when all resquests completed.

    // The result before ordering.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resultPercentage));

    // Just for fun, show the resquest processing order
    console.log(JSON.stringify(responseOrder));

    // Reordering the results, using responseOrder
    //
    for(i=0;i<success_Ajax;i++){
      var index = responseOrder.indexOf(i);
      resultPercentageOrdered.push(resultPercentage[index]);
    }

    // Show them in console.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resultPercentageOrdered));

    // Use this result array here.
    // ...
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Let me try using this and I will let you know soon :)